# ReactiveCocoa implementation of async function

Tags: swift, frp, reactive-cocoa

I would like a review of the RAC implementation for the function `setGist()`
I've posted the code on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/lfaoro/18ca4b63ed982574eec2) for easier reading.

Description:

- You create an instance of `GistService()`
- `let gistService = GistService()`
- Then use public functions `.resetGist() -> Bool` and `.setGist(string: String)  -> SignalProducer<(URL: String, gistID: String), ConnectionError>`

> ```
> gistService.setGist(content: content!)
>     .on(next: {
>         app.userNotification.pushNotification(openURLAction: $0.URL) //this is an NSUserNotification
>     })
>     .on(error: print)
>     .start()
> ```

The function uses the [Gists API](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#create-a-gist)

```
import Cocoa
import ReactiveCocoa
import SwiftyJSON

enum ConnectionError: ErrorType {

    case Bad(String)
    case Worse(String)
    case Terrible(String)
}

/**
- TODO: Add OAuth2 towards GitHub as a protocol
- TODO: Make it RAC
- TODO: Store gistID in NSUserDefaults
*/
public final class GistService: NSObject {

    //MARK:- Properties
    var userDefaults: NSUserDefaults
    var gistAPIURL: NSURL
    var gistID: String?


    //MARK:- Initialisation

    override init() {
        userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        gistAPIURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.github.com/gists")!
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init(apiURL: String) {
        self.init()
        self.gistAPIURL = NSURL(string: apiURL)!
    }


    //MARK:- Public API

    func resetGist() -> Bool {
        //    userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("gistID")
        self.gistID = nil

        return !gistUpdate()
    }

    func setGist(content content: String,
        isPublic: Bool = false, fileName: String = "Casted.swift") // defaults
        -> SignalProducer<(URL: String, gistID: String), ConnectionError> {

            return SignalProducer {sink, disp in

                let gitHubHTTPBody = [
                    "description": "Generated with Cast (cast.lfaoro.com)",
                    "public": isPublic,
                    "files": [fileName: ["content": content]],
                ]

                let request: NSMutableURLRequest
                if self.gistUpdate() {
                    let updateURL = NSURL(string: self.gistAPIURL.path! + self.gistID!)!
                    request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: updateURL)
                    request.HTTPMethod = "PATCH"
                } else {
                    request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: self.gistAPIURL)
                    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
                    request.HTTPBody = try! JSON(gitHubHTTPBody).rawData()
                }

                let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
                let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in
                    if let data = data {
                        let jsonData = JSON(data: data)
                        if let url = jsonData["html_url"].string, id = jsonData["id"].string {
                            sendNext(sink, (url, id))
                            sendCompleted(sink)
                        } else {
                            sendError(sink, ConnectionError.Bad("URL or ID Invalid"))
                        }
                    } else {
                        sendError(sink, ConnectionError.Worse(error!.localizedDescription))
                    }
                }
                task.resume()
            }
    }


    //MARK:- Helper functions

    func gistUpdate() -> Bool {
        guard let _ = self.gistID else { return false }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> /**
> - TODO: Add OAuth2 towards GitHub as a protocol
> - TODO: Make it RAC
> - TODO: Store gistID in NSUserDefaults
> */
> ```

The right way to mark to-dos in Swift is like this:

```
// TODO: Some note about what you need to do.
```

Per [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26869489/2792531), it is the most likely variant that Apple will eventually build into Xcode to automatically generate notes for, but additionally, a script is provided in that answer for generating this warning in the meantime.

---

> ```
> public final class GistService: NSObject
> ```

- It's great that this class is `public`.  It's the only way to use our classes across frameworks... but none of the properties or methods of this class are marked as public.  So realistically, the class really *can't* be used outside the framework it's in.
- Why is this class `final`?  What's the specific problem with inheriting from this class?
- Why is this class inheriting from `NSObject`?  That would make sense in Objective-C (where every class *must* inherit from `NSObject`), but I don't see what we're getting from `NSObject` here.  (In fact, later we'll see that inheriting from `NSObject` actually causes us problems.)
- I'm not sure how much I like the name `GistService`.  Look at the names of Apple classes.  Are any of them "services"?

---

> ```
> override init() {
>     userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
>     gistAPIURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.github.com/gists")!
>     super.init()
> }
>
> convenience init(apiURL: String) {
>     self.init()
>     self.gistAPIURL = NSURL(string: apiURL)!
> }
> ```

First of all, `userDefaults` is unused here and should be eliminated.

Second of all, I'm not sure how appropriate is to default to GitHub.  I just don't know at all how appropriate that is.  If someone using the library wants a more convenient way of instantiating with this (or any other) default base URL, they can always extend the class.

Third of all, strings are not URLs and should not be called as such.

Fourth, and absolutely most importantly, you've done this backwards.  You have the wrong `init` method marked as `convenience`.  I think that inheriting from `NSObject` prevents you from marking the zero-argument `init` has `convenience` (and if so, all the more reason not to inherit from `NSObject`).

The designated initializers should be the ones that take more arguments than anything else.  The *convenience* initializers call those designated initializers.  They are convenient because they take fewer arguments and assume default values for the arguments that the designated initializers require.

So, with all these things in mind... we should start with this `init` method:

```
required init(baseURL: NSURL) {
    self.gistAPIURL = baseURL
}
```

And I'd argue we don't want the zero-argument `init` at all.  (Why this is `required`, I'll address in a minute.)

If we *really* want to provide a means of instantiating with the GitHub url, then that should look something like this:

```
class func gitHubGist() -> Self {
    let gitHubURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.github.com/gists")!
    return self.init(baseURL: gitHubURL)
}
```

We want to return `Self` so that this works with inheritance.  And to do this properly, we have to call `self.init`.  The only way this works with the `Self` return type is if the `init` we're calling is marked as `required`.

So now, if I want a gist of my own choosing, I use this approach:

```
let myGist = GistService(baseURL: fooBarGistServiceAPIURL)
```

And if I want GitHub's, I can conveniently just do this:

```
let gitHubGist = GistService.gitHubGist()
```

---

> ```
> //MARK:- Public API
> ```

This is not how you make methods public.  As I mentioned earlier, our class is public and can be seen outside of the framework... but none of its methods or properties are.  If these methods are intended to be part of the API, we need to start by marking them with `public`.

But that's not enough.  We should also use AppleDoc style comments so that without having to navigate to your website, or where ever you're keeping documentation, the user can get an overview of what this method or property is or does right there in Xcode.

I highly recommend you check out [this NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/) on all of what you can do with AppleDocs, but in the meantime, here's a little preview:

[image]

The comments I provided in lines 5 through 12 generated the content for the pop-up box (which you get by holding Option and clicking the function name).  This documentation crosses file and framework boundaries.  It's the surest way to make sure your documentation is visible to the people actually using your code.  It's comment visible if you're browsing the source and documentation available when you're using the API.

---

> ```
> //    userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("gistID")
> ```

If this code is unused, remove it.  Let [source control](http://importblogkit.com/2015/04/source-control/) manage the fact that it used to be there.  If you don't remove it, some maintainer will.  And if it doesn't need to be removed, it needs a comment explaining why it needs to stay.

---

> ```
> //MARK:- Helper functions
>
> func gistUpdate() -> Bool {
>     guard let _ = self.gistID else { return false }
>     return true
> }
> ```

First, if these are "Helper" functions, they should almost certainly be `private` (they're probably not needed outside this file, are they?).  But problems exist beyond the access level of this method.

What's it even doing?  It's certainly not updating anything.

If I only see the method signature, I see this:

```
func gistUpdate() -> Bool
```

And that's about all I see when I come across it in code (where your library uses it).

So, let's look at the actual implementation:

```
guard let _ = self.gistID else { return false }
return true
```

This is arguably the most confusing way of writing:

```
return self.gistID != nil
```

But this is a really bad method.  We don't need a method for this.  We need optional binding.  If you're not comfortable with optional binding, it's definitely something you need to work on before you venture into anything more complicated in Swift.

So let's take a closer look at where you're calling this method.  Here's a place:

> ```
> if self.gistUpdate() {
>     let updateURL = NSURL(string: self.gistAPIURL.path! + self.gistID!)!
>     request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: updateURL)
>     request.HTTPMethod = "PATCH"
> }
> ```

And this is certainly wrong.  The better approach would start with:

```
if let gistID = self.gistID {
    // we know gistID is non-nil, and it's already unwrapped...
}
```

---

> ```
> enum ConnectionError: ErrorType {
>
>     case Bad(String)
>     case Worse(String)
>     case Terrible(String)
> }
> ```

These classifications for errors are far from sufficient.  The severity of the error should be a sub-property of the classification of the error.  Our errors should be classified into more specific types.  For example:

- No Internet.
- No response from server.
- Invalid credentials.
- Invalid path.

Etc.  This is very simplified and probably not a complete list, but hopefully you get the point.  Now, these should probably still be in an `enum` and still be paired with human-readable string descriptions of the problem, and perhaps a severity indication... but we need to start by classifying the type of error.

Why?

Most importantly, because it will determine how someone using your library will respond to the error.  This will be a far better indicator of the best course of action for responding to the error than some vague severity that you're classifying yourself (and is probably highly subjective generally).

Comment: Thank you very very much for the detailed pearls of wisdom you've shared. I've learnt a lot! I'll be rewriting this class using all of your suggestions and if you'd like I'll send it to you for further review.

Comment: Only one thing I think differently than you and is the Swift documentation. I am using Swift 2.0 and the NSHipster article describes Swift 1.2 syntax which is wrong.

Also, what better name should an webAPI wrapper have than Service? I've been doing some research on naming these things and that's the best I could come up with. I am using the Gist.github.com Service so it makes sense to me, may you expand more on what you think would make better sense?

Comment: Well that's not really wrong so much as a matter of syntax, right?  I don't know what the Swift 2.0 syntax is (I very rarely get an opportunity to write code on the beta versions of Xcode), but I know that there is Swift 2.0 syntax to do exactly this, and you should be using it. Here's a great answer which cover's Swift 2.0 and 1.2: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28633899/2792531

Comment: Do you have any comments for the ReactiveCocoa approach to NSURLSession? Do you use RAC? Is my RAC implementation correct? for `func setGist(content content: String,
        isPublic: Bool = false, fileName: String = "Casted.swift") // defaults
        -> SignalProducer<(URL: String, gistID: String), ConnectionError> {`

Comment: The class is marked as `final` as per Swift best practices guideline: https://github.com/github/swift-style-guide - Classes should start as final, and only be changed to allow subclassing if a valid need for inheritance has been identified. Even in that case, as many definitions as possible within the class should be final as well, following the same rules.

Comment: I think I'd disagree with at least that part of that particular guideline (this is by no means any sort of an official guideline).  Particularly when we keep in mind that you're presenting a library, you should allow consumers of your library to subclass and customize what you provide to them to make it work for their use-case.  You should only mark as `final` stuff that is problematic to the library internally if it is overridden with some sort of different behavior.

Comment: (For example, I also whole-heartedly disagree with that style guideline's suggestion to only refer to `self` where required.)